# browsersync doesn't work with XAMPP

Tags: php, windows, gulp, xampp

I created the project at the address
`D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\optimizedphp (gulpfile.js)`.
What kind of proxy should I use? I tried many, but after changing the php files inside the folder 'app' (`D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\optimizedphp\app`), nothing is restarted.
This proxy doesn't work `localhost:80/dashboard/optimizedphp/app/`

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
       proxy: "localhost:80/dashboard/optimizedphp/app/"
});});
```

Answer (score 0):

First things, first. What happens when you try to access http://localhost:80/dashboard/optimizedphp/app/ on your browser?

Does it open your app correctly?

If it does, try adding `http://` before localhost in your Gulp task, like this:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {

   browserSync.init({
      proxy: "http://localhost:80/dashboard/optimizedphp/app/"
   })
;});
```

Check now, if BrowserSync is correctly pointing to your app.

If it doesn't open your app from http://localhost:80, then there is probably something wrong with your php files or Xampp setup of your project, not BrowserSync.

Comment: 1) The right page opens without browserSync.
2) Same.
http://localhost:80 redirected to http://localhost/dashboard/ and
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/ connected to browserSync

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of trouble with this, but I have it working now, so I thought I might share my config:

```
browserSync( {
    proxy: "https://localhost/mysite/",
    https: {
        key: "W:/xampp/htdocs/mkcert/localhost/localhost.key",
        cert: "W:/xampp/htdocs/mkcert/localhost/localhost.crt"
    }
});
```

NB: I am using xampp and it's installed on W:/ drive. I am also using mkcert for SSL.

You can [learn more here](https://blogjunkie.net/2017/04/enable-https-localhost-browsersync/).